# Which game type earns the most XP in COD Ghosts?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

I'm trying to level up my character in COD: Ghosts multiplayer.  I noticed that in some game types I get good XP in a short time while other games give less even though the games last longer.

Which game type (e.g. Team Deathmatch, Domination, etc) gives the most XP in least amount of time?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this has been written as factual, but **Cranked** appears to be the quickest way to gain XP in a small time frame.

"100 kill tdm with faster movement/pace, xp multipliers for going on streaks, and the matches are way shorter because of the style of play, which means more match bonuses" - [Resource](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/703505-call-of-duty-ghosts/67743881)

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from my own stats on COD:Ghosts, I think Domination provides the highest XP on average, as I earn between 5000 - 10000 XP per game. That's usually 5000 for a loss and 10000+ for a win.

When I first started playing I was using my friends account and was mostly playing Team Deathmatch. The average score I earned on TD was between 2500 - 7000 XP.

I think the difference in score is quite easily achieved by capturing flags worth 150 XP per capture, on top of killing people.

An extra hint which I find quite useful is that using a Support Killstreak with a squad member selected has hidden benefits. Whenever you capture a flag with your squad member you receive twice as many points per capture. If you're able to earn more squad members without letting any die you will receive capture points for every squad member that captures flags with you. That could mean, in a modded game up to 99999 points, you could earn and use an unlimited number of squad members and use them to earn significantly more XP; not to mention how helpful personalised AI support squad members can be in a sticky situation.

I should also mention that if you were to use squad members to this end, you should wait until you've almost earnt your second guy before deploying your first one *and* you cannot hold on to more than one at a time (unused) so don't forget to deploy him before you earn another otherwise it's just a waste.

Answer (score 0):

Something that has helped me a lot is doing drop zone, but using the shield to stay in the area's to get the bonus points from being in the zone. You pick up the packages to defend yourself. I average, depending on my team, 3500 points a game

Answer (score 0):

Play Domination or Cranked.

•Domination-
Domination gives you 150XP for capturing flags. It goes on for about 10-15 minutes and you can get over 10,000 XP from it. When I play, I receive about 15,000-20,000XP every time, while getting about 5 captures and over 20 kills.

•Cranked- 
Cranked allows you to get double XP per kill, while you are cranked. The first kill is 100XP, and while you're cranked, it is 200XP. You only have 30 seconds to get a kill or you blow up.

•Tip- Use Specialist Strike Package, it gives you about 200XP for each new perk you obtain, but only put two perks to have to get 8 kills for your bonus, then you will receive about 250XP for that.

Answer (score 0):

It may be surprising, but it is actually drop zone. I usually on average get between 11000 and 18000 XP per game. Not to mention you get a TON of kills. I am a pretty big noob but in drop zone I usually get over 20 kills and always get a positive KDR. This is my honest opinion

Answer (score 0):

Play domination. I get 20,000 xp cuz i average 25 captures a game. Let the other team get it half way when they are capturing. Then kill and get double the xp for the kill(s) and capture